# Doesn't show H2 tables in browser

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, h2

**Hello,**

*I have a problem with displaying the h2 tables in browser I've created on Java Web Application ( Spring 4, Hibernate 5, Thymeleaf 3, H2database 1.4.192 , etc.).
It has Java-based configuration.*

**My DataSource:**

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    logger.info("Setting dataSource properties.");
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = builder
            .continueOnError(true)
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript(CREATE_SCRIPT)
            .addScript(INIT_SCRIPT)
            .build();
    return embeddedDatabase;
}
```

**My 'CREATE_SCRIPT':**

```html
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS
(
CLIENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL,
AGREEMENT BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS
(
  ITEM_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL,
  PRICE DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTS_ITEMS
(
  CLIENT_ID INT ,
  ITEM_ID INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CLIENTS_CLIENT_ID_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ID)
  REFERENCES CLIENTS(CLIENT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT ITEMS_ITEM_ID_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_ID)
  REFERENCES ITEMS (ITEM_ID)
);
```

**My 'INIT_SCRIPT':**

```html
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES  ('Book', 5.50);
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES ('Hook', 15.00);
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES ('Nook', 199.9);
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES ('Snook', 1.9);
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES ('Stook', 0.99);
INSERT INTO ITEMS
(ITEM_NAME, PRICE) VALUES ('Mobile Phone', 10);
```

***The tables created 100% cuz I  can persist and fetch data.***

> ноя 10, 2016 11:15:59 AM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory
>   initDatabase
>
> **> INFO: Starting embedded database:
>   url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false',
>   username='sa'**
>
> ноя 10, 2016 11:15:59 AM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
>
> INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [create.sql]
>
> ноя 10, 2016 11:15:59 AM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
>
> INFO: Executed SQL script from class path resource [create.sql] in 479
>   ms.
>
> ноя 10, 2016 11:15:59 AM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
>
> INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [test.sql]
>
> ноя 10, 2016 11:15:59 AM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
>
> INFO: Executed SQL script from class path resource [test.sql] in 11
>   ms.
>
> ноя 10, 2016 11:16:09 AM
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager
>   afterPropertiesSet
>
> INFO: Using DataSource
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@162b3d47]
>   of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager

But when I open h2-console and connect to this database with current username and password I can find nothing.

It's very strange and I don't know what the problem is.
Help me please. 
 
Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create an in-memory database

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

which is not persistent and you cannot connect to it via the web console.

see: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

Depending what you want to do

- perist the data --> use a [file based local H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases)
- keep in-memory --> maybe this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077584/h2-database-in-memory-mode-cannot-be-accessed-by-console#5080465) could be a solution

**edit** To add it more in detail.

> In some cases, only one connection to a in-memory database is
> required. This means the database to be opened is private. In this
> case, the database URL is `jdbc:h2:mem:` **Opening two connections within
> the same virtual machine means opening two different (private)
> databases.**

The URL `jdbc:h2:mem:` (an in memory database without a name) creates an database which can be used only with a single connection. A new connection within the same JVM to the URL `jdbc:h2:mem:` would create a new in memory database.

> Sometimes **multiple connections to the same in-memory database** are
> required. In this case, the **database URL must include a name**. Example:
> `jdbc:h2:mem:db1`. **Accessing the same database using this URL only works
> within the same virtual machine and class loader environment**.

The URL `jdbc:h2:mem:db1` (an in memory database with a name, in this case `db1`) creates a database which allows multiple connections. As long the connections are created within the same JVM and class loader.

Comment: Sorry, mate, but it's not a totally correct answer. I'm using Spring MVC.